# How to handle One-to-Many relationship in OData Client?

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a **Web Api 2 Service** and a WPF **OData Client** and I am working with **Crystal Reports**.

I have two tables( **Teacher**, **Subject** ) having **One-to-Many** relationship between them.
I am trying to get **Subjects** against **Teacher_Id**.

Following is the code that I am using:

```
private string ServiceUri = "http://localhost:50623/odata";
    private void pge_TeacherReportPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Container = new Default.Container(new Uri(ServiceUri));
        ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
        report.Load("../../TeacherCrystalReport.rpt");
        var Teacher = from c in Container.Teachers
                      select new
                      {
                         Name = c.Name,
                         FatherName = c.FatherName,
                         ContactNo = c.ContactNo,
                         Address = c.Address,
                         Religion = c.Religion,
                         CNIC = c.CNIC,
                         Status = c.Status,
                         UserName = c.UserName,
                         Subjects = c.Subjects.Where(s=> s.Teacher_Id == c.Teacher_Id).SingleOrDefault()
                      };
        report.SetDataSource(Teacher);            
        rpt_Teacher.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
    }
```

But I am unable to do so as I am getting the Following **Exception**:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.OData.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: Constructing or initializing instances of the
>   type
>   <>f__AnonymousType1`9[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,QuizSystemClient.RestApiOData.Models.Subject]
>   with the expression c.Subjects.Where(s => (s.Teacher_Id ==
>   c.Teacher_Id)).SingleOrDefault() is not supported.

Please tell me how can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved, I had made the following changes in my code.

```
    var Teacher = from c in Container.Teachers
                      select new
                      {
                         Name = c.Name,
                         FatherName = c.FatherName,
                         ContactNo = c.ContactNo,
                         Address = c.Address,
                         Religion = c.Religion,
                         CNIC = c.CNIC,
                         Status = c.Status,
                         UserName = c.UserName,
                         //I had made changes in the following code:
                         Subjects = c.Subjects.Select(s=>s.Subject_Name).FirstOrDefault()
                      };
```